# configure juniper SSL VPN on seperate server for users

Tags: windows, vpn, juniper

we have some client servers in USA and users in our LAN connect these servers using juniper SSL vpn client provided by the client. Now the issue is, numbers of users are increasing here and its been very difficult for us to install juniper vpn client on every user's pc. the solution which we are looking for, to configure any separate windows machine as a vpn which connects to juniper SSL, and all users connect this server and after that they will be able to connect client servers. i am not sure if we can achieve this by using windows routing and remote access. and if yes than how ? any suggestion is highly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's called a site-to-site VPN.  Windows Server can do this, there's some instructions here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687658(v=ws.10).aspx

You'll probably need cooperation from the admin of the Juniper VPN, but Juniper have some details available online: http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB15745

Site-to-site connections are much easier when both ends are running the same thing.  You might want to talk to the Juniper admin about what they are using and invest in matching kit for your end.

Comment: thanx for reply. actually client has provided the juniper vpn and restrict it to only 5 users. we cant not make request to remove or increase the users restrictions. every thing will have to do on our side so that our LAN maximum users can connect to these servers